# Buffer Overrun using a Vector

Tags: c++, buffer, overrun

```
unsigned short* myClass::get_last(size_t _last) const
{
    if (_last == 0) _last = last.size();
    if (_last <= last.size())
    {
        unsigned short* temp = new unsigned short [_last] {};
        while (_last > 0) temp[_last] = last[last.size() - _last--]; //I get a warning HERE
        return temp;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Error!");
}
```

It says:

> Buffer overrun while writing to 'temp': the writable size is '_last*2'
>   bytes, but '_last' bytes might be written.

What does it mean? I know for sure that *_last* is not greater that *temp.size()* because of the `if` so what should I do?

It perfectly works at runtime, but I hate having warnings which make my code less understandable by other user or by me in the future.

---

EDIT:
*_last* is an argument given by the user at runtime, so it could eventually have any value, but if his values are out of the range you get an exception (managed in another function).

The vector that I mentioned in the title is *last*, whis is a member of *myClass*.

I know that the elements of an array go from *0* to *_last - 1*, and this is why I decrement *_last* before using it the first time (as you probably know assignement associativity is right-to-left).

---

I hope I answered all your comments ;)

Comment: How are you using this function? What values could `_last` have? What is `last` and how is it initialized? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `temp` is an array of `_last` elements, and you then write to `temp[_last]`. Are you aware the in C++ array indexes start from 0? Such that the valid indexes goes from 0 to `_last-1`?

Comment: Where are the vectors the question title promised?

Comment: Why do I get the feeling that this code is doing something that could easily be done by using a standard library container?

Comment: ok I edited my post, hope that it is more understandable

Comment: *It says:* -- What is **It**?  The runtime library?  A third-party tool?

Comment: It is a class member from a wider project

Comment: Then I think it's time to give us a [mcve].  Also, when I mean **it**, I am talking about where you got that error text "*Buffer overrun while writing to 'temp': the writable size is '_last*2' bytes, but '_last' bytes might be written*".  That is not a standard piece of text from a compiler, so what tool is giving you this error?

Comment: *and this is why I decrement _last before using it the first time* -- Why write that line of code in such a manner?  What if you simply broke that up into two lines: `while (_last > 0) { temp[_last] = last[last.size() - _last]; --last;}`.  Maybe the way you wrote that line is what is fouling things up.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and this is error C6386

Comment: I tried to divide it but nothing changed

Comment: It is hard to reproduce a minimal reproducible example because there is a whole class which manages this method, but I can tell you that *last* is a `vector` containing some data, which are copied in reverse order into *temp*

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943803/visual-studio-2015-code-analysis-c6386-warns-of-buffer-overrun).

Comment: Thanks, I solved using Vectors like someone said on this article

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved using Vectors!

```
std::vector<unsigned short> Tombola::get_last(size_t _last) const
{
    if (_last == 0) _last = last.size();
    if (_last <= last.size())
    {
        std::vector<unsigned short> temp(_last);
        while (_last > 0) temp[_last] = last[last.size() - _last--];
        return temp;
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Error!");
}
```

For some reason they always solve all problems even if you don't know how ;)

Comment: This is not an answer, only a comment.

Comment: Also still has the buffer overflow except that vector will automatically resize as needed. Inefficient as you are allocating the vector twice.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow the fact is that it doesn't really have buffer overflow because I check its size at line 4, but the compiler does not realize that  because I allocate my content on another vector, which has a size that will never be grater than *last* size

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C++ indexes arrays starting with 0. So an array of size 4 has valid indexes 0, 1,2 and 3.

But you are allocating an array of size _last:

```
unsigned short* temp = new unsigned short [_last] {};
```

and then writing to `temp[_last]`. That is one beyond the size of the array.

Comment: I already verified that __last_ cannot be grater than _temp size_ here `if (_last <= last.size())`

Comment: Yes. But it must be SMALLER. Arrays go from 0 to size - 1.