# Cannot solve warning C6386

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

Please guys I need some help. I get Warning C6386 Buffer overrun while writing to 'AnArray':  the writable size is 'nrows*8' bytes, but '16' bytes might be written. on the following code

```
#include <math.h>

void SubMain(int, int);
int CSTEBit(int, int, int);
double Fact(int);
double Perm(int, int);
int Comb(int, int);

int main()
{
    SubMain(13, 5);
}

void SubMain(int N, int R)
{
    int** AnArray;
    int nrows = Comb(N, R) + 1;
    int ncolumns = 8;
    int Pos;
    int Count;

    AnArray = new int* [nrows];
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
        AnArray[i] = new int[ncolumns];

    for (int a = 0; a < nrows; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b <= 7; b++)
            AnArray[a][b] = 0;
    }


    Pos = 0;
    Count = 0;
    do
    {
        Pos += 1;
        if ((CSTEBit(3, AnArray[Pos][7], 4) == 0) && (CSTEBit(3, AnArray[Pos][7], 5) == 0))
            Count += 1;
    } while (Count != nrows - 1);
    AnArray[Pos][7] = CSTEBit(1, AnArray[Pos][7], 4);
}

int CSTEBit(int CSTE, int Byt, int Bit)
{
    int tempCSTEBit = 0;
    if (Bit < 8)
    {

        int Mask = (int)pow(2, Bit);

        switch (CSTE)
        {
        case 0:
            tempCSTEBit = (int)(Byt && ~Mask);
            break;

        case 1:
            tempCSTEBit = (int)(Byt | Mask);
            break;

        case 2:
            tempCSTEBit = (int)(Byt ^ Mask);
            break;

        case 3:
            if ((Byt & Mask) > 0)
            {
                tempCSTEBit = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                tempCSTEBit = 0;
            }

            break;

        default:
            tempCSTEBit = Byt;
            break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        tempCSTEBit = Byt;

    }
    return tempCSTEBit;
}

double Fact(int N)
{
    double tempFact = 0;
    if (N <= 1)
    {
        tempFact = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        tempFact = N * Fact(N - 1);
    }
    return tempFact;
}

double Perm(int N, int R)
{
    double tempPerm = 0;
    int a = 0;
    double b;
    b = 1;
    if (N < R)
    {
        tempPerm = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        for (a = (N - (R - 1)); a <= N; a++)
        {
            b = b * a;
        }
        tempPerm = b;
    }
    return tempPerm;
}

int Comb(int N, int R)
{
    int tempComb = 0;
    if (N < R)
    {
        tempComb = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        tempComb = (int)(Perm(N, R) / Fact(R));
    }
    return tempComb;
}
```

The variable Pos will never be higher than what Comb function returns which is used to initialize the AnArray. Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: May I suggest you pick up a good book on modern C++ and read it cover-to-cover and then start using containers and smart pointers (if needed at all after adopting containers), and stop trying to manually manage memory like this is C++98 (or earlier). Honestly, this looks like bad C compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Not having one means that each person who tries to help has to get the code compiling before they can even try to reproduce the diagnostic. In this case, it's not even clear whether it's possible to answer the question without majorly guessing the missing parts, which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2015 Code Analysis C6386 warns of buffer overrun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943803/visual-studio-2015-code-analysis-c6386-warns-of-buffer-overrun)

Comment: chris you are absolutely right. I am sorry but this is my first post. I edit the code and now you can reproduce the warning

Comment: It is just a warning.This warning indicates that the writable extent of the specified buffer might be smaller than the index used to write to it. This can cause buffer overrun. In my opinion it may be a code analysis false positive. I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help.

Comment: Perhaps you are right Jeaninez. I guess VS cannot figure out that Pos will never be higher than the size of the array. So I'll just forget about the warning. Thank all for your comments

Answer (score 0):

Well actually I insert "if (Pos < nrows)" inside the do loop after Pos += 1; and the warning was gone.