# (How) Can I get rid of the C6386 warning for post-incremented indexes on arrays to which pointers are initialized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I've asked this question before, but deleted it, because it was unclear, and I couldn't come up with a minimal reproducible example. I'm using a variable `idx` together with the `++`-operator to iterate over an array to add some stand alone data to it, meaning I don't want to put it in a `for`-loop.

Now I did some "research" and I found that this

```
int main()
{
    int idx = 0;
    int integers[6];
    integers[idx++] = 0;
    integers[idx++] = 5;
    integers[idx++] = 3;
    integers[idx++] = 4;
    integers[idx++] = 1;
    integers[idx++] = 2;
}
```

does not cause a warning, while this

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int idx = 0;
    std::string* strings[6];
    strings[idx++] = new std::string("Some");
    strings[idx++] = new std::string("stand");
    strings[idx++] = new std::string("-");
    strings[idx++] = new std::string("alone");
    strings[idx++] = new std::string("data");
    strings[idx++] = new std::string(".");
}
```

causes the following warning when I run the program in debug mode (possibly because [static code analysis is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41944194/11872808)):

> **Warning C6386** Buffer overrun while writing to 'strings':  the writable size is '48' bytes, but '56' bytes might be written.

The marked warning line isn't really important, since VS tends to mark a random line, but it's for me the fourth of the six memory allocations. So I was wondering why I'm getting this warning exactly, if and how I can get rid of it, without changing the `idx++` to hardcoded indexes. I assume the problem is a combination of the `++`-operator and allocating objects.

Important note: this is on Visual Studio, with Debug > Project Properties > C/C++ > General > Warning Level > Level 4 enabled. Also, this is all code causing the warning on my VS.

Here is all I can find in Visual Studio's about (maybe something else is causing this?)

> **Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.5.3)** VisualStudio.16.Release/16.5.3+30002.166
>
> **Microsoft .NET Framework (Version 4.8.03752)**
>
> **Installed Version: Enterprise**
>
> **Visual C++ 2019 00433-90002-07609-AA105** Microsoft Visual C++ 2019
>
> **ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019 16.5.236.49856** ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019
>
> **Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0 16.5.236.49856** Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0
>
> **C# Tools 3.5.0-beta4-20153-05+20b9af913f1b8ce0a62f72bea9e75e4aa3cf6b0e** C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> **Color Theme Designer 1.0** Designer for creating new color themes
>
> **Common Azure Tools 1.10** Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> **Cookiecutter 16.5.20041.1** Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.
>
> **IntelliCode Extension 1.0** IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info
>
> **Microsoft Azure Tools 2.9** Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 - v2.9.30207.1
>
> **Microsoft JVM Debugger 1.0** Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> **Microsoft MI-Based Debugger 1.0** Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> **Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards 1.0** Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards
>
> **Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package 1.0** Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package
>
> **NuGet Package Manager 5.5.0** NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
>
> **Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 16.0** Installs the individual extensions of Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019
>
> **ProjectServicesPackage Extension 1.0** ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info
>
> **Python 16.5.20041.1** Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.
>
> **Python - Conda support 16.5.20041.1** Conda support for Python projects.
>
> **Python - Django support 16.5.20041.1** Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.
>
> **Python - IronPython support 16.5.20041.1** Provides templates and integration for IronPython-based projects.
>
> **Python - Profiling support 16.5.20041.1** Profiling support for Python projects.
>
> **Qt Visual Studio Tools 2.4.3** The Qt Visual Studio Tools allow developers to use the standard development environment without having to worry about any Qt-related build steps or tools.
>
> **Test Adapter for Boost.Test 1.0** Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
>
> **Test Adapter for Google Test 1.0** Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.
>
> **TypeScript Tools 16.0.20225.2001** TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> **Visual Basic Tools 3.5.0-beta4-20153-05+20b9af913f1b8ce0a62f72bea9e75e4aa3cf6b0e** Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> **Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package 1.0** Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>
> **Visual Studio Tools for CMake 1.0** Visual Studio Tools for CMake

Comment: Maybe Visual Studio thinks that the `string` constructor might overwrite the index? I don't believe it has the ability.

Comment: Can't duplicate - https://godbolt.org/z/fQhkGn

Comment: Uh, I'm not familiar with that site, what exactly are you trying to show me, and what do you mean with "can't duplicate"? It throws a lot of windows at me when I open it, so I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: The 1st pane is your test program; the 4th pane is MSVC compiling with no messages at warning level 4 (the middle 2 are clang and gcc).  So with MSVC 19.21 (you can change the version) I can't reproduce the problem you are having.

Comment: Ah, I see. Have you also tried opening it in VS with warning level 4?

Comment: Exactly which version of MSVC compiler are you using ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't find it at the moment. Do you know where to look for the compiler?

Comment: You ccould check the version of the compiler in `Help-> About Microsoft Visual Studio`. I set the `Warning Level` to `Level 4` in visual studio 16.5.3 and 15.9.17 and couldn't reproduce your issue.

Comment: My visual studio version is 16.5.3; I'm not sure if every version of VS has it's own debugger, so I put all about in the question.

Comment: Are you getting this warning when using Analyze->Run Code Analysis->On Solution. In my opinion it may be a code analysis false positive. I suggest you could post the issue to the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) for better help. I suggest you could refer to the link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/41944194/11872808

Comment: I've added the link, but I didn't run the Code Analysis test, if that was a question :/