# Visual studio gives a Buffer overrun warning when overrun can't actually ever happen

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, buffer-overrun

this is my code:

```
void foo(int num) {
    int *pArr = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    // allocate array of 'sale' structs for each region
    for (int i = 0; pArr != NULL && i < num; i++) {
        pArr[i] = 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num = 36;
    foo(num);
}
```

The expression `pArr[i] = 1;` gives a C6386 warning

> Warning   C6386   Buffer overrun while writing to 'pArr':  the writable
> size is 'num*sizeof(int)' bytes, but '8' bytes might be written.

This is very weird since the number of iterations of the `for` loop, AND the size of the array in the head are both dependant on `num` so an overrun can't actually occur ever.

And then there is a detailed explanation:

> `i` may equal 1
> `pArr` may be `NULL` (Continue this loop)
> Invalid write to `pArr`, (outside its writable range)

But of course this is a visual studio mistake, `pArr` cannot be `NULL`, as this is a condition for entering the loop.

How can I clean this warning?
Thank you all

Comment: not related to problem: you need not to check `pArr != NULL` everytime in `for` loop

Comment: @IrAM he needs to check once though.

Comment: Close match: [Visual Studio 2015 Code Analysis C6386 warns of buffer overrun](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41943803)

Comment: @Fredrik, yes that can be done above `for`, guess OP is aware of that, so  dint add it explicitly

Comment: Try `#pragma warning(disable:6386)` ?

Comment: There have been multiple issues opened on Microsoft's Developer Community about C6386 false-positives. For example: [a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adevelopercommunity.visualstudio.com+C6386)

Comment: Note: If you add a test for `num == 0` before attempting the allocation the warning goes away.

Comment: How did you get this warning? I tried compiling this code with VS2019, warning level#4, but did not get any warning.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: @EliyahuMachluf I see the warning on VS2019 release 16.8.3. Do you have Code Analysis disabled or non-default rules configured?

Comment: Code analysis was disabled (by default) on my configuration. I've now turned it on, and I do get this warning.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple change you can make to no longer get the C6386 warning. You should test the value of `num` before attempting the allocation. The C language standard has an interesting statement about passing a size of 0 to `malloc()`.

7.22.3 Memory management functions

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
> implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned to indicate
> an error, *or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value,
> except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an
> object*.

The POSIX standard says something similar:

> If size is 0, either:
>
> A null pointer shall be returned and errno may be set to an
> implementation-defined value, or
>
> *A pointer to the allocated space shall be returned. The application
> shall ensure that the pointer is not used to access an object.*

Microsoft's Code Analysis doesn't emit a C6386 for this code:

```
void foo(int num)
{
    if (num == 0) { // avoid passing 0 to malloc()
        return;
    }
    int *pArr = (int *) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    // allocate array of 'sale' structs for each region
    for (int i = 0; pArr != NULL && i < num; i++) {
        pArr[i] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. avoiding malloc of 0 bytes solves the issue. Still the warning VS gives is enigmatic and not user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because VS seems to be unable to deduce that the loop will never run if pArr is NULL. Replacing your code with

```
void foo(int num) {
    int *pArr = (int *)malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    
    if (pArr == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    
    // allocate array of 'sale' structs for each region
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        pArr[i] = 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int num = 36;
    foo(num);
}
```

will solve your problem and be more runtime-efficient.

Comment: I've tried your suggested code, but it still generates the warning mentioned.